# how to block http requests to some web-pages from adobe air

Tags: apache-flex, flash, url, air, adobe

Is it any way to prevent user to go to specific web-pages using Adobe AIR framework.
I want this software to run at startup and not allowing user to surf some web parts.
I want to use Adobe AIR beacause of its crossplatform capabilities.

Comment: Is this when browsing via the built-in AIR HTML component, or just any browser on their OS?

Comment: Christophe Herreman,  on entire OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While AIR can [detect the computer's connectivity status](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=network_connectivity_1.html), it does not come with the ability to restrict access by other applications.

Comment: maybe i can simply redirect user from unwanted pages to about:blank ?

Comment: Sorry, AIR just doesn't have that functionality built-in.